# Weird resource allocation problem - Thunderbolt3/Wifi/External devices - where to start troubleshooting?

Tags: linux-kernel, hardware, pci

Here the summary of the system and the problem
I have a laptop connected via Thunderbolt3 to a docking station. The dock serves two displays and other devices such as Ethernet, USB audio etc.

What goes wrong:
If I have the laptop with lid closed, i.e. use the docking station, everything works fine but only until I connect to a Wifi network (associated). The very moment I have an asociation, the Dock is ejected(disconnected) and the system suspends. I tried to lock lid-suspend. Same result, but without suspending. If Wifi is just on or scanning it works fine. But now comes the weird part: if the Lid is open, I can work normally also with WiFi.

Here the log that shows what happens

```
[  463.403070] wlp58s0: authenticate with bc:15:ac:72:f8:c9
[  463.408155] wlp58s0: send auth to bc:15:ac:72:f8:c9 (try 1/3)
[  463.414606] wlp58s0: authenticated
[  463.417077] wlp58s0: associate with bc:15:ac:72:f8:c9 (try 1/3)
[  463.421085] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from bc:15:ac:72:f8:c9 (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
[  463.438075] wlp58s0: associated
[  463.497472] wlp58s0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by bc:15:ac:72:f8:c9
[  463.521519] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp58s0: link becomes ready
[  471.380886] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: remove, state 4
[  471.380893] usb usb6: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  471.381087] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: USB bus 6 deregistered
[  471.381097] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[  471.381108] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: remove, state 1
[  471.381111] usb usb5: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  471.381113] apple-mfi-fastcharge 5-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  471.908798] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
[  471.908882] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
[  471.908959] r8152 4-1.2:1.0 enx847beb4fe67e: Stop submitting intr, status -108
[  471.909006] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  471.909018] usb 3-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  471.909122] ipheth 5-2:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet now disconnected
[  471.909435] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[  471.909451] usb 4-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  471.940858] pcieport 0000:05:01.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  472.004920] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[  472.004928] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[  472.005074] xhci_hcd 0000:0a:00.0: USB bus 5 deregistered
[  472.005517] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: remove, state 1
[  472.005524] usb usb4: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  472.006856] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: USB bus 4 deregistered
[  472.006871] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: remove, state 1
[  472.006875] usb usb3: USB disconnect, device number 1
[  472.101150] usb 3-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 4
[  472.104403] usb 3-1.6: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  472.112700] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
[  472.112706] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.
[  472.113625] xhci_hcd 0000:09:00.0: USB bus 3 deregistered
[  472.114909] pcieport 0000:05:01.0: can't change power state from D3cold to D0 (config space inaccessible)
[  472.115216] pci_bus 0000:06: busn_res: [bus 06] is released
[  472.115739] pci_bus 0000:09: busn_res: [bus 09] is released
[  472.116043] pci_bus 0000:0a: busn_res: [bus 0a-38] is released
[  472.116257] pci_bus 0000:08: busn_res: [bus 08-38] is released
[  472.116364] pci_bus 0000:07: busn_res: [bus 07-38] is released
[  472.116539] pci_bus 0000:05: busn_res: [bus 05-38] is released
[  472.136908] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[  472.324795] thunderbolt 0-301: device disconnected
[  472.324971] thunderbolt 0-1: device disconnected
[  473.299513] thunderbolt 0000:03:00.0: 1: DROM device_rom_revision 0x2 unknown
[  473.299519] thunderbolt 0000:03:00.0: 1: DROM data CRC32 mismatch (expected: 0xaf438340, got: 0xaf4383c0), continuing
[  473.306469] thunderbolt 0-1: new device found, vendor=0xd4 device=0xb051
[  473.306475] thunderbolt 0-1: Dell Dell Thunderbolt Cable
[  476.496883] pci_bus 0000:02: Allocating resources
[  477.077544] thunderbolt 0000:03:00.0: 301: no TB_CAP_PLUG_EVENTS, cannot read eeprom
[  477.077550] thunderbolt 0-301: reading DROM failed: -19
[  477.082201] thunderbolt 0-301: failed to initialize port 1
[  477.082532] thunderbolt 0-1: device disconnected
[  477.082655] thunderbolt 0000:03:00.0: no switch exists at 1.1, ignoring
[  477.101560] pool-/usr/libex[9131]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f96d07ff312 sp 00007f96cf8f1ab0 error 4 in libc.so.6[7f96d0741000+195000]
[  477.101573] Code: 84 00 00 00 00 00 66 90 f3 0f 1e fa 41 54 55 53 48 81 ec a0 00 00 00 64 48 8b 04 25 28 00 00 00 48 89 84 24 98 00 00 00 31 c0 <80> 3f 00 0f 84 dd 00 00 00 be 00 08 09 00 e8 5b 38 03 00 89 c5 85
```

The system is a Dell XPS 9350 with TB16 Dock. I updated the firmware of the Dock a week ago which is supposed to fix some issues with the MST displayport firmware. Kernel 5.15.0-71-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-044), updated too last week from 5.15.0-69. Before these updates it worked fine.

Any idea where I can start to solve this problem?
I thought it could have to do with pci IO allocation, due to these messages

```
[   13.300196] pci 0000:08:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[   13.300199] pci 0000:08:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
[   13.300202] pci 0000:08:04.0: BAR 13: no space for [io  size 0x1000]
[   13.300204] pci 0000:08:04.0: BAR 13: failed to assign [io  size 0x1000]
```

Any help is apreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Dock Downgraded. Problem persists. Must be a kernel or othrt sw update problem